# Is there a way to run a for loop in Python without having to pass a list to it?

Tags: python, loops

So, I did a bit of research on this, and the only way I can find to define a `for` loop in Python is to use `for iteratorVariable in someArray`... And this doesn't make sense to me? What if I just want to run a specific block of code x number of times, but I don't want all the extra overhead of having to call `range()` and storing a ton of numbers in a list that I'm never even going to use again...

For example, in JavaScript I could simply say `for(let i = 0;i < 10;i++){}` and it would define a SINGLE variable and increment it by one every time the loop runs, whereas in Python it seems that I'm forced to call a method which returns a massive array of numbers just so that the `for in` loop can iterate over them... And that just doesn't make sense to me. Why would they design their language to only have a single type of for loop, and then force the user to call methods and create variables and lists just to get it to run the way they want?

So my question is, is there a way to run a loop in Python without giving it an array of numbers to iterate over? Can I simply define a variable and increment it by one every frame? Am I forced to use a `while` loop for that purpose?

Comment: range() does not generate a list of numbers any more.  It is a generator. So you can simply use `for _ in range(1_000_000):` to run a loop one million times without generating a million element list first.

Comment: have you tried `i = 0; while i < 10; do whatever you want; i+=1` ?

Comment: Alternate, just do a `for i in range (1, 10):` and it will iterate thru 1 to 9

Comment: Are you sure, in python 3.9.0, it seems to work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python 3 (which you should be using, if you are still using Python 2 by any chance) `range` does **not** "store a ton of numbers in a list". It generates one number at a time by creating a `range` object which uses a math formula (that's how `len(...)` can still work on it in constant time).

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range):

> The advantage of the range type over a regular list or tuple is that a
> range object will always take the same (small) amount of memory, no
> matter the size of the range it represents (as it only stores the
> start, stop and step values, calculating individual items and
> subranges as needed).

Either way, if you still do not want to use `range` (but you really should), you can use a `while` loop.

```
i = 0
while i < 10:
    ...
    i += 1
```

Comment: Great! Thank you. I wasn't aware that they changed the way `range()` works. Thanks for your time, that's good to know! (And yep, I was aware of the `while` lop method, but thank you)

Answer (score 0):

@DeepSpace

'I'm sure that someone can, but no one will. SO is not a solve-my-HW site. Try it yourself and ask specific questions' – DeepSpace Nov 19 '20 at 20:47

Thank you for not helping me that time. You were right I need to do things for myself (Especially homework). After two months I fianlly decided to give the code another go and I completely aced it and got it working.

Thank you :))

Comment: Is there a reason that this was posted on my question, or did you just need somewhere to post it? Am I intended to reply to this or not?